# How to set caret position on a WPF text Editable ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have searched around for a similar question and couldn't find anything.  .Caret doesn't appear to be available and I don't know how to drill down to the textbox or whatever control is embedded within the combobox.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to get at the `PART_EditableTextBox` control from the combo box's control template. The easiest way to do this would be to override [`OnApplyTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.onapplytemplate.aspx) in a derivation of [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx) and then use that derivation wherever you need a combo box with this extended behaviour.

```
protected void override OnApplyTemplate()
{
    var myTextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
    if (myTextBox != null)
    {
        this.editableTextBox = myTextBox;
    }
}
```

Once you have the text box, you can set the caret position, set [`SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart.aspx) to the location where you'd like the caret to appear and set [`SelectionLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength.aspx) to zero.

```
public void SetCaret(int position)
{
    this.editableTextBox.SelectionStart = position;
    this.editableTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: I did something similar to get this working so thanks for the help!  It would be nice if you tidied your answer up a little for people viewing in the future.  Need a void return type on the function, and need to mention that you have to create a new class to derive from the original and have an editableTextBox attribute in there.  Cheers Jeff

Comment: @DrLazer: I added the `void` but it already mentions the need to derive a class. Thanks.

Comment: @DrLazer: Thanks. It's stated in the sentence "...override `OnApplyTemplate` in a **derivation** of `ComboBox` and then use that derivation wherever you need a combo box with this extended behaviour.".

Comment: I would advise to include base.OnApplyTemplate() line. I've had strange behavior without it.

Comment: No need to do the first part anymore with `GetTemplateChild` for "PART_EditableTextBox" element.  The `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` members are directly editable in later .NET veresions.

Answer (score 7):

An even easier way, if you don't want to deal with derived classes, and just want to set the caret for any random ComboBox, is to get the text box from the template (similar to the accepted answer) when you need it, and then just update the caret position directly.

```
var cmbTextBox = (TextBox)myComboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", myComboBox);
cmbTextBox.CaretIndex = 0;
```

Comment: This should be easy enough to convert into an extension method to call on any combo box.